# PC destroyed GPU?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

I've been tearing my hair out for the last couple of hours trying to repair my buddy's PC. Quick summary of what happened:

A few day ago my buddy told me his PC crashed, and when turning it back on there were strange artifacts and the screen would just go black after a minute or so. So i went over, and to confirm it wasn't windows fault we installed a fresh copy, without any effect.

To me it looked like his old Radeon 6850 broke, so we ordered a new GTX 970 and a new PSU (old one wasn't really trustworthy). Today we installed the new one, but there also were Artifacts. I currently have his PC sitting here and testing things, but both GPUs also act up on my personal system. We didn't test the new GPU in a working system, so it may have been dead on arrival (which i kind of hope is the problem...)

Things i've tested so far:
- Installing both GPUs in my system; both are "broken"
- booting his PC from a different HDD; no effect (tested this before the GPUs)

Could it be, that the CPU or the MB fry a GPU? I've heard some people say it's not possible, but others saying the opposite. I could of course test it by installing my own GPU in his system, but i'd rather not :/

If any of you have had a similar case and could help me out here, i would be really thankful!

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious - did you test using two different monitors?

Comment: Yes, 3 actually with both hdmi and DVI

Comment: Is there a bad overclock on the system? Try a cmos reseat.  Are there any integrated graphics?

Answer (score 1):

The PCI-E related VRMs (circuits regulating exact voltage) or other circuits related to PCI-E on the MB may be damaged. It rarely happens, but it can. That can cause video cards to be overpowered and therefore take damage. Assuming there's no overcloking that can affect PCI-E in the BIOS, and since you changed the PSU, your best bet is to get a junk video card, test in on a good system and then test it on the effected one. Also, RMA the new card and when you get a replacement and test it in a good system before anything.
Another test you can do is downclock the GPUs and GPUs RAM and see if artifacts disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have an old GPU laying around, so we're probably going to RMA the card and give the PC to an expert... i'm quite confident replacing the MB will solve the problem, but i don't want to take the risk ^^ I'll reply when i know what the problem was!

Comment: Ok, keep us updated.